# Jquery cookie not being read, or recognized correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have two cookies in this form, one is Text, one is a radio button selection. The text cookie works fine, but the radio button does not.

How its supposed to work:
Input text, make a selection, press button. Sends you to next page where the text is displayed, and the associated number of the radio button is displayed.

What is actually happening:
Input text, make a selection, press buton. Sends you to next page where the text is displayed, but there is nothing from the radio button selection.

Thank you ahead of time.

JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/q7nja8j9/

HTML -

```
<form action="javascript:void(0)">
    <input type="text" name="cookie" id="cookie" value="">
   <div id="pics">



   </div>
   <div id="radio">
   <input type="radio" name="char" id="char1" value="1">
   <input type="radio" name="char" id="char2" value="2">
   <input type="radio" name="char" id="char3" value="3">
   </div>
 <input type="button" name="Fight" id="saveCookie" value="Fight" onclick="window.location.href='Battle.html'">
 </form>
```

JS-

```
$(function(){
    // attach event listener to save cookie button
    $('#saveCookie').click(function(){
        // set cookie expiration to 1 year from today
        var expDate = new Date();
        expDate.setFullYear(expDate.getFullYear() + 1);
        // create cookie string
        var cookieStr = $('#cookie').val() + ";expires=" + expDate.toGMTString();
        // create cookie
        var cookieChar = $('input[name="char"]:checked').val() + ";expires=" + expDate.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = cookieStr;
        document.choice = cookieChar;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is related: [How do I create and read a value from cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)

First of all you have `document.choice = cookieChar;` instead of `document.cookie = cookieChar;`

But from what I have tested it shouldn't work anyway as at the point you have `document.cookie = cookieStr;` the value of cookieStr is something like `abc;expires=Tue, 15 Dec 2015 02:20:13 GMT`, but you need to set a cookie name as well. So it should be:

```
document.cookie = 'cookieName=' + cookieStr;
document.cookie = 'char=' + cookieChar;
```

Is there any reason you're using cookies like this instead of POSTing the form to a server side script (eg. php)? This may help: http://books.msspace.net/mirrorbooks/php5/067232511X/ch04lev1sec2.html

**Javascript cookies**

You need to read this (at a minimum): http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

document.cookies is not a simple string variable, if you try console.log(document.cookies) you'll see something like this:

```
"cookieName=abc; char=2; __utma=45159731; __utmc=45159731;"
```

Which is a concatention of all the cookies set for the page, the part before the = is the cookie name, the part after the = is the cookie value, and the semi-colons separate the cookies. If you set a cookie with no cookie name (as you are doing) the string will look like this:

```
"2; cookieName=abc; char=2; __utma=45159731; __utmc=45159731;"
```

Note the extra "2" at the start. This is why the second cookie is overwriting the first one - because you haven't specified a name for the cookie so it has just re-set the first cookie with the new value.

Comment: Yeah im using cookie's cause it's extra credit for my project. That being said, i dont understand why the text is showing correctly on the next page, and not the radio buttons. The reason i have Document.choice instead of cookie is because im trying to make two different cookies.

Upon changing the document.choice to document.cookie, the radio button works, but now it overwrites the text cookie. How is it possible to have two different cookies?

Comment: by giving them 2 different cookie names (as seen in the code block above), you need to post your code from battle.html where you are retrieving the values from the cookies as you probably have some mistakes there too. Please read the entire answer before asking a question which is already answered, next time.